# Python 3.11. Async test runner

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-3.11, python-3.12

Decided to upgrade Python version from **3.10** to **3.11**, previously we have used `asynctest.TestCase` which has `setUp` and `tearDown` methods and supports testing of async code.

I've checked `unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase` but it uses different event loops for each test that causes usage of different sessions that we can't afford right now.

We are using **async** `setUp` / `asyncSetUp` to initialise dependencies and create test data so this feature is required.

Is there any analogs? Or what you're using for testing complex systems with python 3.11 / 3.12?

p.s `asynctest.TestCase` is not supported in 3.11+

I want to know is there any expertise in testing async code with python 3.11/3.12.
Maybe some one also faced with my problem.

Comment: Have you tried pytest-asyncio? https://pypi.org/project/pytest-asyncio/

Comment: We have thousands of tests written using unittest and using classes described in description. pytest with it's plugins is not aplicable. yes.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.11, [`asynctest.TestCase`](https://asynctest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.test_cases.html) is indeed not supported, and `unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase` does create a new event loop for each test.
That can be problematic when your tests require a consistent event loop across different tests, such as when using shared sessions or connections.

A possible alternative would be to create a custom test case class that *extends* `unittest.TestCase` and manually manage the event loop. That would allow you to use the same event loop for all tests, similar to how `asynctest.TestCase` worked.

```py
import asyncio
import unittest


class AsyncTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    loop = None

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print("Setting up test case class")
        cls.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(cls.loop)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print("Tearing down test case class")
        cls.loop.close()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(None)

    def run_async_test(self, coro):
        print(f"Running async test: {self._testMethodName}")
        return self.loop.run_until_complete(coro)
```

The `run_async_test(self, coro)` method is used to run an asynchronous test. It takes a coroutine as an argument, runs it to completion using the event loop stored in the loop class attribute, and returns the result.

That does create a single event loop in the `setUpClass` method and use that same event loop for all tests in the class. This is different from the [`unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase) class, which creates a new event loop for each test.

That should allow you to write test methods as asynchronous (`async def`) and have them executed properly within the `unittest` framework.

For instance, using it in a test would be:

```py
# tests/test_async_module.py
from tests.async_test_case import AsyncTestCase
from async_modules import async_add


class TestAsyncModule(AsyncTestCase):
    def test_async_add(self):
        print("Starting test_async_add")

        async def coro():
            print("Starting coroutine in test_async_add")
            result = await async_add(5, 3)
            print("Finished awaiting in test_async_add")
            self.assertEqual(result, 8)

        self.run_async_test(coro())
        print("Finished test_async_add")

    def test_dummy(self):
        print("Running test_dummy")
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

with:

```py
# async_module.py
import asyncio


async def async_add(a, b):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)  # Simulate an async operation
    return a + b
```

Full project at [`VonC/AsyncTestCaseExample`](https://github.com/VonC/AsyncTestCaseExample).

I get:

```bash
C:\Users\vonc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe C:\Users\vonc\PycharmProjects\AsyncTestCaseExample\__main__.py 
Setting up test case class
Starting test_async_add
Running async test: test_async_add
Starting coroutine in test_async_add
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 1.016s

OK
Finished awaiting in test_async_add
Finished test_async_add
Running test_dummy
Tearing down test case class

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: unittest.TestCase does not have run_async, it has only run method, how do you expect to run this? Thanks for reply. Respect your contribution.

Comment: Looks like you just copied some code from a library). It would not work this way.

Comment: Also we can't use a new loop or close the old one because sessions that we are using is bind to loop and we ought to dispose our db. This was mentioned in original post.

Comment: @AndrewHolovko OK. I have rewritten the answer to take that into account. I have tested that new approach in a project  available at [`VonC/AsyncTestCaseExample`](https://github.com/VonC/AsyncTestCaseExample): it compiles and run '`def async`' tests, using one single event loop.

Comment: I cant rewrite 3k tests this way.

Comment: I already found the solution keep up with updates.

Comment: @AndrewHolovko Sorry, I spent some time on testing my solution, so I might have missed your update: I look forward to reading your solution.

Comment: I've used unittest.TestCase with aiounittest.async_test to use async methods for tesitng.
Also I've created metaclass that adds this async_test (decorator) to each async function.

Comment: @AndrewHolovko OK, can you write an answer here describing that in detail? That will help others.